# Calculating depth of a well by dropping an object

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acoustics

If given the speed of sound and the time (from dropping the object to hearing the sound of the object hitting water).

How do you calculate the depth of the well?
Usually we use   $y=\frac 12 gt^2$ but then there is the time
It takes for the sound to travel from the bottom to the top.

Comment: What is "y=12gt2y=12gt2" supposed to mean?

Comment: If the well is deep enough that the time for sound to get back is noticable, the dropped object has probably accelerated enough for air friction to become important. If so, $y = 1/2 gt^2$ isn't the right equation to use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Depth of a well](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/311748)

Answer (score 2):

If the time it takes for the object to reach the bottom is $t_1$ and the time it takes for the sound to reach the top is $t_2$, their sum $t_1 + t_2 = T$ would be the time measured from the instant you let go of the object to the instant your device picks up the sound of the hit at the bottom. Then, since
$$
t_1 = \sqrt{\frac{2y}{g}}
$$
and
$$
t_2 = \frac{y}{v},
$$
where $v$ is the speed of sound at your location, if you add these two to get T you can get a quadratic equation by changing variables $\sqrt{y}=u$ and solve that.
If this is meant for something like a school experiment I would assume that $y$ is not that great a distance and $t_2$ would probably be negligible.